# Yii2: How to configure boolean labels globally?

Tags: boolean, yii2, label

I have boolean in my database. How to configure (globally) the names for my boolean lables in my app?
I'd like to set it like:

```
'1' => 'OK',
'0' => 'NOT OK'
```

and display it like that everywhere in my app (in views, forms, gridview, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [$booleanFormat](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#$booleanFormat-detail) property of `yii\i18n\Formatter`.

Via application config:

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'formatter' => [
            'booleanFormat' => ['NOT OK', 'OK'],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Or at runtime in specific place:

```
Yii::$app->formatter->booleanFormat = ['NOT OK', 'OK'];
```

Comment: Thank you!
But what if I want to configure the "booleanFormat" just for a particular boolean in particular table? Is it possible to configure it for a particular boolean somewhere in the model, where this boolean is preconfigured?

Comment: @Publius You can use the latter option. Just set it before rendering table.

Comment: ok, but what if I have 2 different booleans, and one of them should be ['not ok', 'ok'] and second one ['yes, 'no']? That is why I wanted to set those values globally somewhere in the model maybe, so that all other files will inherit those values for particular boolean. :)